# How to return json object from servlet using angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, json, servlets

I want to return my json object from servlet in angularjs i wrote an angular app it's not giving any error but it's not getting data too. I can not search correctly because my english some insufficient can some one help me about that please
Here my code

Angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
        {{ x.1}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("first").then(function (res) {
        $scope.myData = res.data.jso;
    });
});</script>>
```

And here my doGet method my json object it's inside ;

```
    @Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);    

        while (rs.next()) {


            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();

            jso.put("1", rs.getString(1));
            jso.put("2", rs.getString(2));
            jso.put("3", rs.getString(3));
            jso.put("4", rs.getString(4));
            jso.put("6", rs.getString(6));
            jso.put("8", rs.getString(8));
            pw.print(jso);         
        }
        conn.close();
        rs.close();
        pw.close();
        stmt.close();
        pw.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Cab you try with x["1"]?

Comment: use `console.log($scope.myData);` and see what it will print

Comment: I tried both of it, but not worked no error no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i wrote an angular app it's not giving any error but it's not getting data too.

In your call you didn't implement error callback so instead:

```
$http.get("first").then(function (res) {
    $scope.myData = res.data.jso;
});
```

Change to:

```
$http.get("first").then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    $scope.myData = res.data.jso;
}, function (error) {
   console.error(error);
});
```

It will give you more info about problem

Comment: It worked chrome was not showing error. I opened with mozilla i got my data in console but i can't see on the page.Where did i mistake?

Comment: @TPBAFK can you please post log ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6vEgdFyd  I chanced (x.1) to (x.res) and same problem no error, no data in html. Just in console and there is no error in theconsole

Comment: @TPBAFK your data is under `data` key. However it looks like HTML structure and not JSON.